# click to open panel and click again to close while panel is open unity2d ui c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing streaming app on Unity and I try to create video player like youtube as click to open and close panel while panel is open. I use startcouroutine to open panel temporarily and want to close it while panel still open. However; it seems like it close before sec time.

```
private void Start()
{
    canvasGroup = panel.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
    canvasGroup.alpha = 0f;
    onOpen = false;
}

public IEnumerator TempPanel()
{
    canvasGroup.alpha = 1f;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(sec);
    canvasGroup.alpha = 0f;
    onOpen = true;
}

public void Paneltemp()
{
    if (canvasGroup.alpha == 0)
    {
        StartCoroutine(TempPanel());
    }
    else if (canvasGroup.alpha > 0)
    {
        canvasGroup.alpha = 0;
        StopCoroutine(TempPanel());
        sec = 5f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Where are you calling the function `Paneltemp` from? Please share more code so we can get a better idea of what is going wrong.
However, from what I can see it looks like you've got to set the `sec` variable before calling the `TempPanel` coroutine, as otherwise it defaults to 0 which could cause the error you mention. If `sec` will stay constant, then just set it in the Start function, as below:

```
sec = 5f;
```

Then you won't have to change it anywhere else in the script.

Answer (score 0):

This is solution and thank you for racism hater who always click minus to me.

```
private void Start()
        {
            
        canvasGroup = panel.GetComponent<CanvasGroup>();
        canvasGroup.alpha = 0f;
       
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(canvasGroup.alpha == 1)
        {
            autoCloseTimer += Time.deltaTime;
            if(autoCloseTimer >= autoCloseInterval)
            {
                canvasGroup.alpha = 0.99f;
                StartCoroutine(Close());
                ResetAutoCloseTimer();
            }
        }
    }

   

    public void Paneltemp()
    {
        if(canvasGroup.alpha == 1)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Close());
        }
        else
        {
            StartCoroutine(Open());
        }
        
    }

    IEnumerator Close()
    {
        while (canvasGroup.alpha > 0)
        {
            canvasGroup.alpha = 0f;
            
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Open()
    {
        while (canvasGroup.alpha < 1)
        {
            canvasGroup.alpha = 1f;
            
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    void ResetAutoCloseTimer()
    {
        autoCloseTimer = 0.00f;
    }
}
```